# SQL (ASA v9) concatenate multiple return values

Tags: sql, concatenation

I have seen similar questions answered by "**use FOR XML PATH**", but for **FOR XML** ASA V9 only has the options **AUTO, EXPLICIT** and **RAW**.

I have two tables:

```
PATIENT (patient_id, visit_id)
TREATMENT (visit_id, treatment_id)
```

and I want to join them to return:

```
patient_id, visit_id, treatment_id
```

where the last value is a concatenation of all the treatments for that visit.

Answer (score 1):

[LIST](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/list-function.html) function is your answer:

```
SELECT p.patient_id, p.visit_id, LIST(t.treatment_id, ',') as l
FROM PATIENT p INNER JOIN TREATMENT t
ON p.visit_id = t.visit_id
GROUP BY p.patient_id, p.visit_id
```